# Linux serial port read() returns the maximum buffer size passed in

Tags: linux

```
unsigned char buf[256];
num = read (fd, &buf, sizeof (buf));
```

I have a program that reads the serial port at 100ms rate. Device can send a maximum of 120 bytes of data every 100ms. I am observing at times that read() returns 256 (the size of buf[], that I have passed in to read() ). Because of this all the bytes are mixed up and I see checksum failures.

Is there a way, that I can poll on the file descriptor if there is a data and read only the valid data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!  You can use the functions `poll()` or `select()` to know when data is available, but you will not know exactly how much.  For that you can either do a regular blocking read of 120 bytes if it's a fixed-size message each time, or you'll have to read smaller parts, like the header first then the body once you know the size from the header, or you can read big chunks into a ring buffer and process them however you want in user-space.

Comment: Yeah. I have tried using select() but still the problem persists that read() returns max buffer size. I just wanted to know is there a way that I can get an interrupt when the data becomes available to be read. And I can read byte by byte instead of passing the whole buffer to the read() API.

Comment: You can read one byte at a time but it will not be efficient.  Better is to read a big chunk into your buffer and process the part you want, keeping the rest for later when you can read more to get the next message.